# Refactoring onload to add a second function? Bonus: what about adding second functions to variables in general?

Tags: javascript, function, onload

I have two questions in sequence?

I have two sets of code I'm refactoring. Each has an onload.

Both will run by themselves on a site, but I don't want them overwriting the onload of eachother.

So I have the equivilent of:

```
window.onload=function(){ alert("foo")};
```

and

```
window.onload=function(){ alert("bar")};
```

in two files.

To avoid one overwriting the window.onload assignment of the other, I refactored them to this:

```
window.onload+=function(){ alert("foo")};
```

and

```
window.onload+=function(){ alert("bar")};
```

but then it seems neither fires.

And since it seems like it'd help me understand the situation and just generally be a decent skill to have, how do I add additional functions to a function variable? (Is it the same as with onload, or is onload a special case? It strikes me like something that may have a special case.)

So if I had...

```
var Varrick = function(){ alert("Do the thing!");}
```

and I had

```
var Zhu_li = function (){ alert("Did the thing."); }
```

What would effectively be the command

```
var Varrick = Varrick + Zhuli.
```

so...

```
Varrick(); // Alerts "Do the thing!" then alerts "Did the thing."
```

*Note: I want to do this without relying on jQuery.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one reason why assigning to `on-` properties often isn't a great idea - if anything previously existed on that property, it will be overwritten, so only the latest handler will fire. (and don't try to `+=` functions to each other)

Try adding `DOMContentLoaded` listeners instead:

```
function foo() {
  console.log('foo');
}
function bar() {
  console.log('bar');
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", foo);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", bar);
```

> how do I add additional functions to a function variable?

If you *have* to have only a single listener, then just call both functions in the listener:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  foo();
  bar();
});
```

which is like

```
window.onload = function(){
  foo();
  bar();
};
```

(but, generally better to use `addEventListener`)

Comment: Any answer for the second part?

Comment: Have a function that `calls both functions` as shown with the listener

Comment: And then re-assign that function to the original function name?
So it'd be like _var Bob = function () {Varrick(); Zhu_li();}; Varrick = Bob;_ ?

Comment: Reassigning function names is almost always a *very* bad idea. You'd have to make another separate reference to the first function in order to call the first function's name later and have both the first and second execute. Very messy, just use a better method to accomplish your goal

Comment: Seems like doing so should be a general extension of one of the touted core strengths of JavaScript, "everything's an object" though. Basically continuing on the concepts of the advantages of assigning a function via _var foo = function(){};_ instead of _function foo(){}_ would be to do something like that.

Comment: Well, it's pretty trivial to achieve manually if you really need something like that. `const joinFunc = (...funcs) => () => funcs.forEach(func => func());` then call `joinFunc`